# Drupal 7 Internationalization / Multi language : redirect to default language if translation missing for article

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-7, translation

I'm new to the Internationalization for Drupal 7 and here is what I'm trying to do.

Let's say i have 3 languages for my site. English, French and Dutch. What I want is when an article is not translated in a specific language, to see the English version of the article.

I could write my article in English, then use the neutral language to make sure the article appears in every language, but then I can't translate the article in just French or just Dutch.

Example:
I created an article in English.
I translated it in French.
I haven't translated it in Dutch, but I still want the English version of the article to appear in the Dutch version of the site.

If anyone has any idea I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

(Basing this off my installation of Drupal 6, you may have to look a bit further if you can't find the same options)

On the Site Configuration options, go to Languages and then "Multilingual System". In Drupal 6 this comes with the i18n module; I believe it's core functionality in Drupal 7. For content selection, choose the option "Mixed current language (if available) or default language (if not) and language neutral". Also, ensure that English is set as your default language.

Comment: all right thanks, i'll look into this as soon as i can but i've been redirect on something else at the moment. Once i've looked into it, i'll come back and give more information if it turned to be it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Select translation module for the above issue.
you can find module at https://drupal.org/node/1098708.

in views add filter : Select translation
  In Select translation selection mode 
   Use current language ; if not available use default language ; if not available use original language.