# Drupal 7 Internationalization : redirect to default language if translation missing

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-7, translation, multilingual

I am building a multilingual site with Drupal 7 and Internationalization. Everything works perfectly except one thing. I want to redirect to the default language if the translation is missing for one node. I thought that the module "Translation redirect" would be enough but it does not seem to work.

I have seen that someone had a similar issue here : [Drupal 7 Internationalization / Multi language : redirect to default language if translation missing for article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999799/drupal-7-internationalization-multi-language-redirect-to-default-language-if)

I want to do the exact same thing. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GlobalRedirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module and set the option '**Language Path Checking**' to true in the module configuration page.

[image]

Alternatively you can use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) or a custom module like the one described in [drupal-redirect-when-missing-node-translation](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/01/17/drupal-redirect-when-missing-node-translation/) to handle the redirect.

Comment: Thanks much! I already have Rules enabled so I guess I'm gonna give it a try that way. If it doesn't work, I'll use Global Redirect. Thanks for your time and help!